# What is the difference between bash as a default shell and running 'bash'?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I set up `subl` command in `~/bin` 
But I couldn't run the command `subl` unless I run `bash` in my terminal. I thought changing default shell from `zsh` to `bash` would fix it but it did not. I still have to run `bash` before `subl` and this is annoying.

- What's the difference between default `bash` and command `bash`?
- Why `subl` wouldn't work until I run `bash` and what should I do to make it work?

I've just started learning actual computer and I know these could be silly questions. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
TORIs-MacBook-Pro:~ taro$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash
TORIs-MacBook-Pro:~ taro$ subl --help
-bash: subl: command not found
TORIs-MacBook-Pro:~ taro$ bash
bash-5.0$ subl --help
Sublime Text build 3211
```

Comment: Yes I did install bash 5.0 using brew trying to solve the problem. `type -a bash` says `bash is /usr/local/bin/bash<br>
bash is /bin/bash` and `type -a subl` returns `-bash: type: subl: not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Execute `~/bin/subl`

Your `subl` command located in `~/bin` (very often equivalent to `/home/user/bin`) is probably not in `zsh`'s `PATH` variable :

The command interpreter doesn't look everywhere on you computer when you execute a command, it has a few directories to search in. This list is stored in an environment variable called `PATH`. It contains something like this :

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

In my case, `~/bin` is not in the list, but I can add it for this session only executing `PATH="$PATH:~/bin"` or include it when zsh starts by adding this line to ~/.zshrc :

```
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

Now my PATH is :

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:~/bin
```

### Change the default shell

I'm not sure how it works with macOS X, but on Linux to change the default shell you need to execute this command line :

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

> **NOTE** : the argument following -s **must** be a path to an interpreter, like bash.
>
> You can found its path with `which bash` for example.

Then just relaunch your terminal or log out and in.

> **important** : see first comment below about the tilde expansion (thanks to @Charles Duffy)

Comment: Note that on many shells (I can't speak to zsh), `PATH="$PATH:~/bin"` won't work because `~` is not expanded in quotes on POSIX-y shells; it would thus need to be either `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"` or `PATH=$PATH:~/bin` -- removing either the tilde, or the quotes.